# Files owned by root:root when using actions/checkout on self-hosted runner

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I have a GitHub Actions workflow running on a self-hosted runner that looks like this:

```
---
name: Workflow

on:
  workflow_call:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    
    steps:
    - name: Cleanup build folder
      run: |
        rm -rf /home/github/actions-runner/_work/* || true

    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        fetch-depth: 0
```

The issue I'm facing is that sometimes the files that are checked out are owned by root:root (randomly, it seems), which makes the first step fail. This forces me to clean up the self-hosted machine manually before being able to re-launch the workflow.

Rolling back to `actions/checkout@v2` does not seem to solve the issue for me.

One solution is to run the first step as `sudo`, but I'm not comfortable changing the configuration so it doesn't ask for the password when executing `rm`.

Comment: Have you verified that it's not the issue with the already committed files in the repo? And, on your self-hosted runner, no other interference of any kind affects these files?

Comment: Where does the need to run `rm -rf /home/github/actions-runner/_work/* || true` stem from? Can yo elaborate on that? I ask because so far I was under the impression this should never be necessary to do in a workflow and I'd like to better understand your question.

Comment: There should be no interference on the self-hosted runner. @hakre , it is because I'm using a self-hosted runner that is not cleaned up by GitHub at the end of the execution of the workflow, so it's necessary to do it manually

Comment: Ah, okay, perhaps make it a janitor job on that system that removes files from time to time because when it happens while you run this, what happens with parallel workloads? (Or do it always after the run? - Won't change for the sudo issue, thought, so more food of thought than a direct useful suggestion) But as you've maybe read out of me asking is that my knowledge about self-hosted runners falls pretty short.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the files owned by root come from jobs that use containers, since most containers run as root - and most importantly/non-intuitively, GHA mounts existing local folders as the drive for containers.  I found that setting my containers to run as the same UID/GID as my GHA runner user on the host solved the issue.